# SQLite database construction in a C++/MFC application is running to slow as the amount of data increases

Tags: c++, performance, sqlite, mfc

To sum it up, our problem is the following:

our `C++/MFC` application, with a `SQLite` database backend, is running too slow as we increase the amount of data stored in it, that amount of data not being huge at all.

Here are some details.

Our program is a `C++/MFC` program.
We are using `SQLite` databases to store our data.

Given two source files that we want to compare, the `first step` in using our application, consists in `building a data set` stored in tables in a SQLite database.

These two source files basically contain tuples that we want to pair given a common criterium.

For example, a source tuple can be:

```
1|A00001|0003139289341|1717154207941|@001160816373000049|Foyer|Canapé simili rouge 280|2900.0|Allen|Banquette "Dossier et Accotoirs"|||1970-01-01
```

It's neither original nor complicated or huge or anything special.

For files containing `2,000` lines (tuples), this first step, takes some acceptable time, like no time.

But for files containing `8,000` lines (tuples), it takes really too much time for the database to be constructed (more than `four minutes`).

An operation such as creating a table (`CREATE TABLE`) and inserting one tuple in that newly created table (`INSERT INTO`) takes `39 seconds` and meanwhile the application puts itself in "`Not responding`" status which is pretty disagreeable and particularly `not expected`.

A long time ago, we discovered that even a read-only operation should be put inside a `transaction` to speed the operation up and that's what we have been doing since then.

Note that running the application on a `6 GB` or a `16 GB` RAM machine doesn't change anything.

We have measured times between the procedure main phases but we do not manage to figure out what's going wrong, what is slow and why.

Is there someting we can do **at SQLite level**, like setting up a `PRAGMA` with a specific value which would accelerate the process?

Thanks.

===========================
Edit 1

I start the application in `Debug` mode from `MS Visual Studio`.
I stop the application by closing the application window.

I get 475 memory leaks like this one:

```
{93} normal block at 0x01FAEB08, 18 bytes long.
 Data: <hX—             > 68 58 97 01 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
```

Can you please tell me how I can manage to find where the leaks are coming from?

===========================
Edit 2

If I comment the `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` call in `ExitInstance()`, I do not get the memory leaks detected above.

===========================
Edit 3

We have discovered other leaks that are more meaningful to us (obviously related to our code).

Originally, we created our `MS Visual Studio` project with the `Not Set` `Character Set`.

At some point in our code, we have a function `F` with lines like:

```c
CStringW szwquery = L"";
int n_ret = 0;

    szwquery = L"INSERT INTO [...]";
    n_ret = m_pDoc->m_SqliteDb.ExecuteSql(&(m_pDoc->m_SqliteDb), szwquery);
```

In the end, `ExecuteSql()` resolves to:

```c
n_res = sqlite3_prepare16_v2(
        mp_db,
        sz_stmt,
        -1,
        &p_stmt,
        0);
```

where `sz_stmt` type is `CStringW`
(`mp_db` type is `sqlite3 *`
`p_stmt` type is `sqlite3_stmt *`)

In the function `F`, we repeatedly run `INSERT` (and `UPDATE`) statements like this:

```c
szwquery = L"INSERT INTO [...]";
n_ret = m_pDoc->m_SqliteDb.ExecuteSql(&(m_pDoc->m_SqliteDb), szwquery);

szwquery = L"UPDATE [...]";
n_ret = m_pDoc->m_SqliteDb.ExecuteSql(&(m_pDoc->m_SqliteDb), szwquery);

szwquery = L"INSERT INTO [...]";
n_ret = m_pDoc->m_SqliteDb.ExecuteSql(&(m_pDoc->m_SqliteDb), szwquery);

szwquery = L"UPDATE [...]";
n_ret = m_pDoc->m_SqliteDb.ExecuteSql(&(m_pDoc->m_SqliteDb), szwquery);

[...]
```

As the memory leaks are linked to these lines, we suspect the issue might come from here.

Comment: Is the SQLite database file on your local system?

Comment: Yes, it is a local database. Thanks.

Comment: A [profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/) will help you understand where your program is spending its time. Without gathering this insight you (and we) are left with guessing.

Comment: Well, my question was more about is there something I can do at SQLite level... Yet, I started a "profiling" in release mode in MS Visual Studio a few hours ago and it's still running. Presently, using "Process Explorer", I can see a stable ~8.32% CPU usage, 26.7 MB private bytes (stable), absolutely 0 I/O activity.

Comment: The code should take at most a few seconds (<10) to insert all the lines.  Something is very wrong.  What's the create table code? How are you connecting to SQLite?

Comment: I don't know if this applies for SQL Lite but for me, I have to call `EnableSQLTrace( FALSE );` before working with Microsoft Jet else it is way too slow for me. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/methods-auto/debugger/debugger-enablesqltrace-method. Also, have you tried temporarily switching off antivirus? Anything database related I think may cause some scanning. I could be wrong.

Comment: does the behavior change, if you copy the records to a in-memory/shared-cache database? `sqlite3_open("file::memory:?cache=shared", &db);`

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I understand we will have to examine the code more closely. @IInspectable: I used "Alt+F2" in "MS Visual Studio" to launch the "Performance Profiler". Yesterday, at bed time, the operation had not completed and still not in the morning. I realized that the ".vsp" report file generated had filled my whole disk space. It's size was 250 GB. Hopefully my computer was still functionning but I think the program running in VS had stopped running a long time ago even if the window was still there "greyed", "frozen", unresponsive. (1/2)

Comment: I re-launched the profiler and stopped it after the first slow down. This time, ".vsp" file was 9 GB large. I could see nothing obvious when it opened in VS. Earlier, you pointed me towards a very general Web link. Can you advise me a tutorial or a book or something more friendly than a Web page a with all its links that do not allow me to grasp the problem globally? Thanks. (2/2)

Comment: CPU sampling can get you a rough overview of where a program spends time. It's better suited to performance issues that are compute bound. I doubt that you are in that situation, and [instrumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/understanding-performance-collection-methods-perf-profiler#instrumentation) is a better fit. I'm sure there are many resources detailing how to interpret profiling results. You'll have to go looking, probably towards articles that cover lock contention (as that's what the problem sounds like).

Comment: The (potential) memory leaks are likely a different, unrelated issue. MFC's leak detection is based on the assumption that modules get unloaded in reverse order in which they were loaded, a property that's near impossible to establish. You'll have to figure out whether those are actual memory leaks, and once that is done take it from there. That's a difficult task, and I'm not aware of any resources that would make it easier.